# The game closes if you choose to buy a second item in the shop

Tags: batch-file, variables, command-prompt

I know this question is subjective, but could someone please help? I'm sure this is a very stupid question and can easily be fixed.

If you save and run this code in a batch file, and after making a name, if you try to buy more than one item, the game will close. I don't know if it has to deal with the variable name. I have some sample code of my game here:

```
title Hack Wars by Geeketek
color 0a
@echo off

:new
set mon=500
set mas=1
set mult=1
set pop=0
set prot=100
set maxprot=100
set pc=None
set av=None
set ht=None
cls
echo What's your name?
echo.
set /p name=Enter:
goto main

:shop
cls
echo HACK WARS - SHOP
echo ----------------------------------------
echo %name%   Money: $%mon%
echo ----------------------------------------
echo.
echo PCs: (currently using %pc%)
echo 1a) Blarqu 13       $200      Mastery: 1
echo 1b) Lonevo Power    $600      Mastery: 3
echo 1c) Ledd v2         $1200     Mastery: 6
echo.
echo Antiviruses: (currently using %av%)
echo 2a) NoVi Basic      $100      Mastery: 1
echo 2b) GetSecure       $500      Mastery: 3
echo 2c) Master Pro      $1000     Mastery: 7
echo.
echo Hacking Tools: (currently using %ht%)
echo 3a) DDOSer          $100      Mastery: 1
echo 3b) Cracker         $600      Mastery: 3
echo 3c) Hack Pro        $1100     Mastery: 7
echo.
echo 4) Back
echo.
set /p choice=Enter:

if %choice% == 4 goto main


if %choice% == 1a (
if %mon% LSS 200 goto nofunds
set mon= %mon% - 200
set pc=Blarqu 13
goto purchase
)

if %choice% == 1b (
if %mon% LSS 600 goto nofunds
set mon= %mon% - 600
set pc=Lonevo Power
goto purchase
)

if %choice% == 1c (
if %mon% LSS 1200 goto nofunds
set mon= %mon% - 1200
set pc=Ledd v2
goto purchase
)


if %choice% == 2a (
if %mon% LSS 100 goto nofunds
set mon= %mon% - 100
set av=NoVi Basic
set maxprot=100
set prot=100
goto purchase
)

if %choice% == 2b (
if %mon% LSS 500 goto nofunds
set mon= %mon% - 500
set av=GetSecure
set maxprot=150
set prot=150
goto purchase
)

if %choice% == 2c (
if %mon% LSS 1000 goto nofunds
set mon= %mon% - 1000
set av=Master Pro
set maxprot=200
set prot=200
goto purchase
)


if %choice% == 3a (
if %mon% LSS 100 goto nofunds
set mon= %mon% - 100
set ht=DDOSer
set maxprot=200
set prot=200
goto purchase
)
if %choice% == 3b (
if %mon% LSS 600 goto nofunds
set mon= %mon% - 600
set ht=Cracker
set maxprot=200
set prot=200
goto purchase
)
if %choice% == 3c (
if %mon% LSS 1100 goto nofunds
set mon= %mon% - 1100
set ht=Hack Pro
set maxprot=200
set prot=200
goto purchase
)

goto shop


:nofunds
cls
echo You don't have enough money
echo to purchase this item.
pause >nul
goto shop

:nomas
cls
echo Your mastery isn't high enough
echo to purchase this item.
pause >nul
goto shop

:purchase
cls
echo Thank you for your purchase.
pause >nul
goto shop
```

Comment: in :new, where it says goto main, change it to goto shop

Comment: You never bothered to read the [2-minutes tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), did you?

Comment: no, i literally just started using stack overflow xD im a nub

Answer (score -1):

I changed all the numeric variables to set /a and that solved the problem.